# Drawing text inside UITableView - text does not show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to iOS, so it's probably something very simple. What important - I want to use drawing, not adding subviews. And I need to do it on public method. Trying to do it like so:

```
@implementation TripTableViewCell2

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)updateWithTrip:(Trip*)trip
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColorFromRGB(0x28cdfb)};
    CGSize textSize = [trip.tripId sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    CGPoint textPoint = CGPointMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
    [trip.tripId drawAtPoint:textPoint withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

I assume I miss something simple like setting context for drawing but not sure.. Also, is there any one-line command to wipe OFF anything drawn inside this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call drawAtPoint, it draws into the current context which is not the context of the cell.

What you need to do instead is create a subclass of UIView and do your drawing in the drawRect method. Here I have created such a class and tested that it works as expected:

```
#import "CustomDraw.h"

@implementation CustomDraw

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSString *trip = @"My trip";
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]};
    CGSize textSize = [trip sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    CGPoint textPoint = CGPointMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
    [trip drawAtPoint:textPoint withAttributes:attributes];
}


@end
```

[image]

One way to show the view in a table cell is to set it as the background view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TripCell"];
        cell.backgroundView = [[CustomDraw alloc] init]; // Pass your trip in here

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSString drawAtPoint:withFont:` makes use of the context stack, and from where I was calling this method the stack was empty. Wrapping the call with

`UIGraphicsPushContext(context); and UIGraphicsPopContext();`
did the trick.